how to capture Google Live Caption text?
Google chrome Live Caption feature allows the display of live speech of videos such as youtube etc in the chrome browser.
In a PC running chrome, it is possible to locate a window/form titled ' live caption' via the task lists with windowapi using any development tools ( eg Microsoft vb, vc++ etc ) as below. Is there a way to get the text from this window?
 EnumWindows AddressOf EnumWindowsProc, 0&


PS. add a image from inspect.exe


You can try UI Automation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/entry-uiauto-win32 and before coding anything you can use UIA tools to check if it's possible or not: Inspect (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/inspect-objects) is kind of legacy or Accessiblity Insights: https://accessibilityinsights.io/

yes, the text can be found in inspect.exe. The text is not in the window with title 'live caption' , but one of the childs.

So you can write UIA code to get it
